# Permissions between users

Tags: facebook, permissions

I'm working on an app which pulls a lot of data from Facebook, so I'm caching that data to avoid making a whole bunch of requests. I still update the data regularly and use the Real-time updates to make it more efficient. But now, I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what data the user has access to. Here's an example :

UserA is in the "Family" friendlist of UserC
UserB is in the "Work" friendlist of UserC

In this case, UserC set different permissions for his family friendlist and his work friendlist. So UserB doesn't have access to all the data that UserA has access to.
Now my question is, if I cache the data, how do I know which data(about UserC) that UserB is allowed to see?

This is a case with friendlists, but Facebook allows us to specifically determine which person has access to which piece of data, which makes it even more complicated.

It seems to me that there should be something where you can specify two users and see the permissions between the two of them, similar to the /mutualfriends thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty certain there is no chance to find out which permissions a user set for each friend list, since it is a **global** privacy setting, hence confidential. If you could, you would probably find this information in the [FriendList](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/) connection of the [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object, but there is no such information. The only privacy information you can query is information with reference to specific objects (a post, video, note, link, photo, photo album) or an app. Apps can set app specific or object specific privacy settings but not global privacy settings. Hence apps can read app specific privacy settings but still cannot read global privacy settings.

Comment: Hmm.. What bugs me though is that you get that information for things like posts, albums (and more) with the "privacy" field that is set to something like "EVERYONE", "FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS", or even "CUSTOM" if it's a friendlist or whatever. 
But there's no such thing for profile info (like work, education, etc.)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a few more late evening thoughts.

Comment: That makes sense, but still doesn't solve my problem. I guess it's up to me to figure out a way to save what user has access to what cached data. Just a quick idea here, I could probably save what fields the user sees and only show those fields to him. A bit like the privacy settings on the objects, except those privacy settings are never showed to any user (since it's confidential). It's only for data caching purposes.

Comment: Yap, you could do that. How you handle user data (whether you expose it to others or not) is always your own decision. However keeping private data private is principally a good idea.

Comment: Yeah and it's against Facebook policies to show private data that a user usually cannot see